# Fix for a broken Vim/Syntastic/Vundle?

Tags: linux, troubleshooting, vim-plugins, syntastic

*[Vim 8.1 - Syntastic 3.9.0 - Vundle 0.5 on Arch linux]*

This morning I started getting error:

> syntastic: warning: checker vim/vint: unrecognized error format
>   (crashed checker?)

The message appears every time I write buffer to disk, i.e. everytime Syntastic is invoked (?). Have been trying to unravel the mystery ever since.

The vundle doc is available in buffer with `:h vundle` and `:Plugin<Tab>` does propose completion with the usual choice of possibilities (`PluginInstall`, `PluginClean`, `PluginList`, etc..) but none are functional.  This had me thinking that I had a Vundle problem.
The corresponding runtime path in `~/.vimrc` is correctly set to `rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle`, the which correspond to my clone git repo for Vundle. The local repo clone is up to date.

`:SyntasticInfo vim` does show `vint` as linter So things seem to work there.

I am stumped. Any suggestion anyone ?